# Does someone know of some fixed pipeline shader tutorial or samples?

Tags: directx, direct3d, shader, direct3d9

I am  making a game with 3d gamestudio a8 free edition. The free edition doesn't support shader, it only supports fixed pipeline shaders. There are some samples in the wiki of 3d gamestudio ([click here](http://www.opserver.de/wiki/index.php/Shaders#Fixed_function_effects_.28are_working_with_all_3DGS_Editions.29)) but I want to know of there are more samples or tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a good starting point would probably be the DX10 example [FixedFuncEMU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416406%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The unity3D guys also implemented one for [DX9 shaders](http://aras-p.info/texts/VertexShaderTnL.html)...